# Definition of isobaric process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, definition

I have a doubt on the definition of **isobaric** process in thermodynamics, which of the two is the correct?

$(A): \mathrm{d}p=0$ (there are no variation of pressure during the process at all)

$(B): p_{\mathrm{\, final \, state}}=p_{\mathrm{\, initial \, state}}$ (the final pressure is equal to the initial pressure)

Of course $(A)$ is stronger since $(A)\implies (B)$.

In other words: is the process in picture **isobaric**? ($B$ is satisfied, $A$ is not)

[image]

Comment: I would only consider $A$ to be isobaric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process is reversible, then A is correct.

If the process is irreversible, then we only have control over the externally applied pressure $P_{ext}$, which matches the force per unit area of the gas only at the piston face.  Within the gas, the pressure and temperature can be non-uniform in an irreversible process, and viscous stresses contribute to the overall forces per unit area.  If, in an irreversible process, we suddenly increase or decrease the external pressure $P_{ext}$ at time zero and hold it at this value during the entire deformation, we typically refer to this as a *constant-pressure irreversible process*, even though the imposed external pressure is not equal to the gas pressure in the initial equilibrium state, and, even though the external pressure only matches the force per unit area of the gas at the piston face.  Of course, the work in this case is $P_{ext}\Delta V$.

Comment: With reference to his graph, i dont think he has plotted an irreversible process.

Comment: Yes.  I wouldn't consider it isobaric.

Answer (score 0):

Only A is isobaric. B is not. Isobaric processes are defined as a thermodynamic process A-B, in which $\partial$p/$\partial$T  and $\partial$p/$\partial$V are zero for all (T,V) € (A-B), where A-B denotes the process from state A to B. Clearly, B does not satisfy this.